# How can I avoid killing my code on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management, out-of-memory, kill, oom

I'm trying to run my code which is supposed to calculate molecular descriptors, but it gets killed by an Out-of-memory error, even though (I think?) I have enough memory to process it. How can I edit my code to avoid killing by OOM? The file 'Data.csv' contains ~62k rows with string data inside.

```html
import deepchem
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tempfile

from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
import deepchem as dc

from deepchem.utils import download_url, load_from_disk
from simtk.openmm.app import PDBFile
from pdbfixer import PDBFixer

from deepchem.utils.vina_utils import prepare_inputs
import pandas as pd
import os
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

pdbid = data['pdb_id'].iloc[1]
ligand = data['smiles'].iloc[1]

fixer = PDBFixer(pdbid=pdbid)
PDBFile.writeFile(fixer.topology, fixer.positions, open('%s.pdb' % (pdbid), 'w'))

p, m = None, None
# fix protein, optimize ligand geometry, and sanitize molecules
try:
    p, m = prepare_inputs('%s.pdb' % (pdbid), ligand)
except:
    print('%s failed PDB fixing' % (pdbid)) 

if p and m:  # protein and molecule are readable by RDKit
    print(pdbid, p.GetNumAtoms())
    Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToPDBFile(p, '%s.pdb' % (pdbid))
    Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToPDBFile(m, 'ligand_%s.pdb' % (pdbid))

pdbids = data['pdb_id'].values
ligand_smiles = data['smiles'].values


l = []
for (pdbid, ligand) in zip(pdbids, ligand_smiles):
  fixer = PDBFixer(url='https://files.rcsb.org/download/%s.pdb' % (pdbid))
  PDBFile.writeFile(fixer.topology, fixer.positions, open('%s.pdb' % (pdbid), 'w'))
  
  p, m = None, None
  # skip pdb fixing for speed
  try:
    p, m = prepare_inputs('%s.pdb' % (pdbid), ligand, replace_nonstandard_residues=False,
                          remove_heterogens=False, remove_water=False,
                          add_hydrogens=False)
  except:
    print('%s failed sanitization' % (pdbid)) 

  if p and m:  # protein and molecule are readable by RDKit
    one = Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToPDBFile(p, '%s.pdb' % (pdbid))
    two = Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToPDBFile(m, 'ligand_%s.pdb' % (pdbid))
    l.append(p)
    l.append(m)

proteins = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if len(f) == 8 and f.endswith('.pdb')]
ligands = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.startswith('ligand') and f.endswith('.pdb')]

# Handle failed sanitizations
failures = set([f[:-4] for f in proteins]) - set([f[7:-4] for f in ligands])
for pdbid in failures:
  proteins.remove(pdbid + '.pdb')

pdbids = [f[:-4] for f in proteins]
small_dataset = data[data['pdb_id'].isin(pdbids)]
labels = small_dataset.labels
fp_featurizer = dc.feat.CircularFingerprint(size=2048)
features = fp_featurizer.featurize([Chem.MolFromPDBFile(l) for l in ligands])
dataset = dc.data.NumpyDataset(X=features, y=labels, ids=pdbids)
a = dataset.to_dataframe()
a.to_csv('descr.csv')
```

[screenshot of OOM error and memory status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7kAt.png)

Comment: why do you create l and then overwrite it? Don't use 1-letter names.

Comment: You mean the list which expands to create the output csv file? How would you change this?

Comment: How long does your program run before it crashes?

Comment: About half a day